# New implementation of a library function and calling the old implementation within that

Tags: c++, c, linux

I want to implement some custom library functions in Linux. For example, I want to implement my own **pthread_mutex_lock**, **pthread_mutex_unlock**, **malloc** and **free** functions. I've read **LD_PRELOAD** can be used to use your own custom functions, although I haven't got into the details.

But I have one question, I also want to use the original functions within my new implementations. What would be the trick to do that, as both would have the same names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `dlopen` function to open the library you replace (or use RTLD_NEXT if it is already loaded, see comments), and then use `dlsym` function to find the address of the function in that library that you want to call.

Comment: Sounds like a nice idea, will look into it. Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't even need to open the library you're interposing - using `dlsym(RLTD_NEXT, "function")` should be sufficient to find the original implementation.